# MFC Class Wizard will not delete a control's member variable

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019, classwizard

I'm using VS 2019, working in C++. I created a property page with a few combo boxes and edit controls. For reasons I don't understand, the dialog editor decided one of the "custom" member variables in the class was attached to one of the Edit controls. What I mean is, when I run the Class Wizard and go to the "Member Vaiables" tab, it shows what should be a Custom variable as being attached to one of the Edit Controls. When I highlight it and press "Delete Variable", it does nothing. Here's what I've tried:

- Removed the variable and confirm the class wizard no longer shows it. Put it back and is connects it to the Edit control again.
- Changed the type of the variable. No effect.
- Changed the name of the variable. No effect.
- In the Class Wizard I tried adding the variable through the "Add Custom" dialog. It tells me the variable already exists.
- Deleted and recreated the Edit Control. With a different ID. The wizard then shows the member variable as "custom". However, when I change the ID back to the original ID, it automagically links it up with the Edit Control again, so I really haven't solved the problem.

I don't know if this is related, but when I press "Delete Variable" I always get an error pop-up that says, "Index and length must refer to a location within the string." But I get this no matter what variable I delete and in the other cases it still deletes the variable.

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a way I can manually unlink remove this association?

Comment: With the class wizard broken for two decades now, I haven't kept up with what it does. At the code level the association between class members and UI controls is done from within the `DoDialogExchange` implementation through one of the `DDX_` routines (see [TN026: DDX and DDV Routines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn026-ddx-and-ddv-routines) for reference). I don't know whether that's the only data the class wizard uses to determine associations.

Comment: It looks like a bug in VS Class Wizard. I could easily reproduce it. The only thing to do I think is just go into the code and delete all references manually.

Comment: You could report this issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=62&entry=problem).

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT the class wizard has become virtually unusable many years ago, I believe the last one that worked properly was in Visual Studio 6.0.  So I'm not sur MS will ever fix it.

Comment: Here is my prediction: A potential defect report will eventually have a bot leave the following reply: *"I detected that this issue hasn’t received a lot of activity, votes, or comments \[...\], it’s my experience that this issue is unlikely to get fixed."* Microsoft doesn't care about its native developer platform anymore. The amount of neglect is staggering.

Comment: I was surprised — and shocked — that MFC originating from 1992 is still being maintained.  The current version is MFC 14.31.30818 released with Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 (17.1.0).  I recommend trying out the current version (if you are able to), and see if the bug is still there.  If the bug is still there, file a bug report.  MFC is provided with [*full source code*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/using-the-mfc-source-files?view=msvc-170), so alternatively you can fix the bug yourself.

Comment: @tromgy - I'm not sure what you mean by delete all references manually.  What references should I be looking for in the code?

Comment: I meant to delete any (additional) references that ClassWizard (possibly) created -- check if it created any DDX_ bindings for this variable and delete them.